# optional parameter in flatiron/director

Tags: javascript, url-routing, flatiron.js

Is it possibile create a route with optional parameter in flatiron/director?

```
var router = Router({

    'order' : function(){
        // create a order
    },

    'order/:orderId' : function(orderId){
        // load order by id
    }
}).init();
```

Can I use one single route to manage the edit/load order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [director docs](https://github.com/flatiron/director#url-matching):

```
var router = Router({
  //
  // given the route '/hello/world/johny/appleseed'.
  //
  '/hello': {
    '/world/?([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)/?': function (a, b) {
      console.log(a, b);
    }
  }
});
```

Basically use regex instead of simple `:tokens`

`johny` and `appleseed` become optional parameters.